# how can I make charAt method work with arrays in java?

Tags: java, charat

can someone help me with this problem ? i have to make method charAt to work but i dont know how..

```
class AsciiCharSequence implements java.lang.CharSequence/* extends/implements */ {
    // implementation
    byte[] array;

    public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] array) {
        this.array = array.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return array.length;
    }

    *@Override
    public char charAt(int i) {
        return (char) array.length(i);
    }*
```

Comment: `return (char) array[i];` (although the explicit cast is unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public char charAt(int i) {
    return (char) array[i];
}
```

Since you have an array and want to return the character at a particular array. In your question you are not returning a particular index value.

Comment: Although explicit casting is not a good practice, try avoiding it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to access element in the array. But do not forget about throwing required exception, like it declared in `CharSequence` documentation (if you access not correct element in an array, another type of exception will be thorwn).

```
public class AsciiCharSequence implements CharSequence {

    private static final char[] EMPTY_ARRAY = new char[0];

    private final char[] arr;

    public AsciiCharSequence(char[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr == null || arr.length == 0 ? EMPTY_ARRAY : Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
    }

    private AsciiCharSequence(char[] arr, int start, int end) {
        this.arr = arr == null || arr.length == 0 || start == end ? EMPTY_ARRAY : Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return arr.length;
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= length())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        return arr[i];
    }

    @Override
    public AsciiCharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        if (start < 0 || end < 0)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        if (end > length())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        if (start > end)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        return new AsciiCharSequence(arr, start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(arr[i])).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding about character set can be refer below code from  **AbstractStringBuilder**

```
 @Override
public char charAt(int index) {
    checkIndex(index, count);
    if (isLatin1()) {
        return (char)(value[index] & 0xff);
    }
    return StringUTF16.charAt(value, index);
}
```